# React router, path vs object, matching issues

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have some strange issues with the react router:

```
 <Link to={{
pathname:
     '/hols/tenerife/costa-del-silencio/alborada-beach-club.html',
    query: { param1: 'true' }
    }}>Go to page A</Link>
```

matches

```
<Route path="/hols/:country/:area/:hotel" component={MyLayout} />
```

yet this doesn't match the same route (it hits my 404 route):

```
<Link to="/hols/tenerife/costa-del-silencio/alborada-beach-club.html?param1=true">Go to page A</Link>
```

Then... when you try to match on hash and try to pass in string to the to attribute you get the opposite results. i.e. this:

```
<Link to="/hols/tenerife/costa-del-silencio/alborada-beach-club.html?param1=true#hashparam=true">Go to page B</Link>
```

matches this:

```
<Route path="/hols/:country/:area/:hotel?:foo#:bar" component={MyLayoutB} />
```

but this doesn't:

```
    {{<Link to={
                      {
                        pathname: '/hols/tenerife/costa-del-silencio/alborada-beach-club.html',
                        query   : { param1: 'true' },
                        hash    : '#hashparam=true',
                      }}
                    >
                      Go to page B
                    </Link>}}
```

If anybody has experience with the react-router, their help would be much appreciated. **Is this expected behaviour?** The problem we have is that as we migrate to react, our pathnames and search strings need to remain the same, and for new features we will be matching on the hash params.

Note that the page needs to match the route, once the page is refreshed. Currently the ones that work above, do, however I have had instances where they don't and go to my 404 react route.

Comment: Note, i'm using v2.x.x and also note https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#link-to-onenter-and-isactive-use-location-descriptors